# Pandas dataframe to string manipulation

Tags: pandas

The model I'm working with requires two sets of input:

1. an item tuple of feature name and value of feature
2. A list of all possible unique values for all features.

Below is a minimial working example of how I am doing it right now. This works perfectly well for small datasets. When scaling to over 100K rows and 100 columns, this gets extremely slow.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'user': ['u1','u2','u3', 'loc'],
        'f1': [1, 0, 1, 'del'],
        'f2': [1, 1, 1, 'mum'],
        'f3': [0, 0, 1, 'del']
       }
features = pd.DataFrame(data,  columns = ['user', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'loc'])

def enrichFeatures(feature_set=None, col=None):
    RemainingFeatures = [*feature_set]
    RemainingFeatures.remove(col)
    feature_list = []
    for user in feature_set[RemainingFeatures].values.tolist():
        feature_list.append(
            [str(feature_name) + ":" + str(user_feature) for feature_name, user_feature in zip(RemainingFeatures, user)]
            )
    item_tuple = list(zip(feature_set[col].values.tolist(), feature_list))
    unique_column_values = []
    for rf in RemainingFeatures:
        for unique_value in feature_set[rf].unique():
            unique_column_values.append(str(rf) + ":" + str(unique_value))
    return item_tuple, list(set(unique_column_values))

item_tuple, unique_vals = enrichFeatures(feature_set=features, col='user')
[('u1', ['f1:1', 'f2:1', 'f3:0', 'loc:nan']), ('u2', ['f1:0', 'f2:1', 'f3:0', 'loc:nan']), ('u3', ['f1:1', 'f2:1', 'f3:1', 'loc:nan']), ('loc', ['f1:del', 'f2:mum', 'f3:del', 'loc:nan'])]
print (item_tuple)
['f1:0', 'f2:mum', 'f3:0', 'f3:del', 'f1:1', 'f1:del', 'loc:nan', 'f3:1', 'f2:1']
print (unique_vals)
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to approach this.

Testing function

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100000,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
def timing_val(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        if 'log_time' in kw:
            name = kw.get('log_name', method.__name__.upper())
            kw['log_time'][name] = int((te - ts) * 1000)
        else:
            print ('%r  %2.2f ms' % \
                  (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000))
        return result
    return timed

@timing_val
def stack_out(features, col):
    trans_dict = features.T.to_dict()
    unique_vals  = []
    item_tuple = []
    for _, z in trans_dict.items():
        i = z.pop(col)
        z = [key + ':'+ str(value) for key, value in z.items()]
        unique_vals  += z
        item_tuple.append((i, z))

    unique_vals  = list(dict.fromkeys(unique_vals)) #removes duplicates
    return item_tuple, unique_vals

@timing_val
def enrichFeaturesV2(feature_set=None, col=None):
   rf = [f for f in feature_set if f != col]
   df = feature_set.groupby(col).apply(lambda x:[f'{k}:{x[k].tolist()[0]}' for k in rf]).reset_index()
   unique_column_values = [f'{f}:{v}' for f in rf for v in feature_set[f].unique()]
   return list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)),list(set(unique_column_values))

@timing_val
def enrichFeatures(feature_set=None, col=None):
    RemainingFeatures = [*feature_set]
    RemainingFeatures.remove(col)
    feature_list = []
    for row in feature_set[RemainingFeatures].values.tolist():
        feature_list.append(
            [str(feature_name) + ":" + str(feature_value) for feature_name, feature_value in zip(RemainingFeatures, row)]
        )
    item_tuple = list(zip(feature_set[col].values.tolist(), feature_list))
    unique_column_values = []
    for rf in RemainingFeatures:
        for unique_value in feature_set[rf].unique():
            unique_column_values.append(str(rf) + ":" + str(unique_value))
    return item_tuple, list(set(unique_column_values))


stack_out(df, 'A')
enrichFeatures(feature_set=df, col='A')
enrichFeaturesV2(feature_set=df, col='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, it assumes unique users and uses an apply function. On the small dataset posted your method seems faster at a time of 00.000998 where mine is 00.003989 but on a larger dataset of 100 000 x 100 like you mentioned the times become 03.951706 for yours and 00.704110 on the new function.

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

#Original function
def enrichFeatures(feature_set=None, col=None):
    RemainingFeatures = [*feature_set]
    RemainingFeatures.remove(col)
    feature_list = []
    for user in feature_set[RemainingFeatures].values.tolist():
        feature_list.append(
            [str(feature_name) + ":" + str(user_feature) for feature_name, user_feature in zip(RemainingFeatures, user)]
            )
    item_tuple = list(zip(feature_set[col].values.tolist(), feature_list))
    unique_column_values = []
    for rf in RemainingFeatures:
        for unique_value in feature_set[rf].unique():
            unique_column_values.append(str(rf) + ":" + str(unique_value))
    return item_tuple, list(set(unique_column_values))

#New function
def enrichFeaturesV2(feature_set=None, col=None):
    rf = [*feature_set]
    rf.remove(col)
    df = feature_set.groupby(col).apply(lambda x:[f'{k}:{x[k].tolist()[0]}' for k in rf]).reset_index()
    u_col_val = [f'{f}:{v}' for f in rf for v in feature_set[f].unique()]
    return list(df.itertuples(index=False,name=None)),list(set(u_col_val))

#Testing
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 100)), columns=['user']+[f'f{x}' for x in range(99)])

t1 = datetime.now()
enrichFeatures(feature_set=df, col='user')
print(f'inital = {datetime.now()-t1}')
                  
t2 = datetime.now()
enrichFeaturesV2(feature_set=df, col='user')
print(f'new = {datetime.now()-t2}')
```

edit: I updated the function since I found using your method for finding the remaining features to be more efficient and increased the overall speed of the function

Comment: I used df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 100)), columns=['user']+[f'f{x}' for x in range(99)]) to generate the dataframe of 100000K rows

Comment: Your version takes 5993.36ms, while the one posted in the question takes 673.06ms. Could you explain how you computed the time?

Comment: I just took the datetime before and after, how are you taking the time of the one before? Having 673.06ms seems very fast to me and I doubt anyone can beat that. Are you passing the new large data set to both cause when I do that I was getting a time of 3.951706s for the one above? I did notice though my method was only faster on a large dataset not the small one you supplied.

Comment: I tested it on a large dataset of 100K rows and 100 cols. what did you test on?

Comment: I took the time using the timeit decorator. added the code to the question